# Burninate the [required] tag

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [required](/questions/tagged/required) has no tag wiki to it and it seems like a meta tag considering items tagged with it alone couldn't stand on its own.

Just a sample of what this tag contains:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721736/is-quickbooks-sdk-necessary-on-client-machine-to-establish-connection-with-quick
- [How to change my validation to make field optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883076/how-to-change-my-validation-to-make-field-optional)
- [SQL select query with one or two column excluded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057343/sql-select-query-with-one-or-two-column-excluded)
- [MVC Required Field not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706846/mvc-required-field-not-working)
- [required or required = "required"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982868/required-or-required-required)

Can this be burninated?

Comment: Yeah, seems like any question that has "required" somewhere in the body/title gets this tag...